# Google Drive API caching query results

Tags: android, caching, google-drive-api

I want to check if a folder exists in the `root` of the linked Google Drive account. If it exists, delete a file in that folder and create a new one in there. If it doesn't, create the folder and then create a file in it.

This is what I'm doing to query:

```
private void checkIfBackupFolderIsInDrive(final File databaseFile) {
        final Query backupFolderQuery = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(Filters.and(
                        Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, DATABASE_BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME),
                        Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE),
                        Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)))
                .build();

        mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder()
                .continueWithTask(task -> {
                    final DriveFolder rootFolder = task.getResult();
                    return mDriveResourceClient.queryChildren(rootFolder, backupFolderQuery);
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(mActivity, metadataBuffer -> {
                    for (final Metadata metadata : metadataBuffer) {
                        final DriveFolder driveFolder = metadata.getDriveId().asDriveFolder();
                        final String title = metadata.getTitle();
                        final String mimeType = metadata.getMimeType();

                        if (title.equals(DATABASE_BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME) && mimeType.equals(DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE)) {
                            Utils.log("SettingsFragment", "Backup folder already exists");
                            deleteExistingDatabaseFileInFolder(driveFolder, databaseFile);
                            metadataBuffer.release();
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    metadataBuffer.release();
                    createFolderToRootDriveFolder(databaseFile);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(mActivity, e -> Utils.log("SettingsFragment", "Error retrieving files list: " + e.getMessage()));
    }
```

As you can see, I'm already calling the `release()` method on the `metadataBuffer` but when I delete the recently created folder, even emptied from the Trash and then execute the query again, it keeps saying that the folder already exists.

If I do not empty the trash, the new file is created inside the trashed folder.

I am using this version of the `drive` API alongside with this version of the `auth` API:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1'
```

This is driving me nuts. How can I perform a clean query to avoid that behaviour to happen?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: please include the exact error message returned from google

Comment: @DaImTo there's no error message returned from Google. The code just acts as everything is correct because of the `metadataBuffer` not being cleared even when calling the `release` method.

Comment: **it keeps saying that the folder already exists.**  then who says it exists?

Comment: @DalmTo my log inside the `OnSuccessListener`: `Utils.log("SettingsFragment", "Backup folder already exists");`. So according to Google, everything went well. And it did, but the information is not up to date. But I already sorted it out. Take a look at my answer below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of energy spent on data research, I found the solution. Before making any query / operation that requires an up to date metadataBuffer you must call `DriveClient.requestSync()` to update it.

But be careful when using this method. According to the documentation below:

> `public abstract Task<Void> requestSync ()`
>
> Requests synchronization
>   with the server to download any metadata changes that have occurred
>   since the last sync with the server.
>
> Typically, this method should be called when the user requests a
>   refresh of their list of files. Once this method returns, performing a
>   query will return fresh results.
>
> In order to avoid excessive load on the device and server, sync
>   requests are rate-limited. If the request has been rate-limited, the
>   operation will fail with the DRIVE_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED status. This
>   indicates that a sync has already occurred recently so there is no
>   need for another. After a sufficient backoff duration, the operation
>   will succeed when re-attempted.
>
> Source: [Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveClient#requestSync()).

My implementation is as follows:

```
private void refreshMetadata(final File databaseFile) {
    mDriveClient.requestSync()
            .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> checkIfBackupFolderIsInDrive(databaseFile))
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Utils.log("SettingsFragment", "Could not update metadata buffer: " + e.getMessage()));

}
```

I request the sync. If successful I start the operations that I want to do. If it fails right now I'm only logging the event.